# Iterate queue element until outofrange

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to iterate every element of a data queue once (`num_epochs=1`) but I don't know in advance how many items I have. Queues have `num_epochs` option and can throw an `outOfRange` error. How can I catch this in a while loop ?

Comment: I found my answer in https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py

Comment: If you're up for it, post a well-written answer below, using examples from your link.